# Bitnami Redmine - Development Process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, bitnami

I would like to install `Redmine` using the `Bitnami` stack. I have to build custom NEW pages in `Redmine` and perform some reporting - hence play around with some `ROR` code.

Can you please suggest me a good development process, as I will have to stop and restart `Redmine`'s service upon every change.

Should I not use `Bitnami` for development (develop with a thin server first) and at the end merge/replace my files in `Bitnami`'s `Redmine` folder?

Answer (score 1):

You could switch to rails `development` environment. In this mode source code files are read by server upon every request.

1. Change `database.yml`, so it will have the same configuration options as in production mode. It is better to create separate database for `development` environment, but not necessary, since you're already developing in production.
2. Find your web-server configuration file and change in there environment to `development`.

There is other simpler way. Since (for now) you are interested only in source code updates per request, you can change only one parameter in rails configuration to do so. Open `config/environments/production.rb` and change line

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

to

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

Usually this option set to `false` in `development` with the following comment:

```
  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the webserver when you make code changes.
```